# How to use timespan by years using kusto ago function?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I was trying to filter my table data using ago() function. However, it accepts only seconds, min, months and days. Is there anyway to filter the data by years?

```
T | where TimeStamp > ago(5s) --> works
T | where TimeStamp > ago(5m) --> works
T | where TimeStamp > ago(5d) --> works
T | where TimeStamp > ago(2y) --> Doesn't work with years
```

Is there any other way to easily lookup by years? Other than using ago(365d) or ago(730d)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`datetime_add()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-addfunction):

`T | where TimeStamp > datetime_add('year', -2, now())`